# iOS Facebook sdk - Cannot get publish permission and post status

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-graph-api, permissions

I have been following Facebook's guide and trying to update status through my iOS app. While trying to update my status to my timeline, I checked if I have publish permission and requested it if it is absent with the following code:

code in GraphViewController.m:

```
- (IBAction)postClicked:(id)sender {

if([self.status_input isFirstResponder])
    [self.status_input resignFirstResponder];

if ([FBSession.activeSession.permissions
     indexOfObject:@"publish_actions"] == NSNotFound) {
    // No permissions found in session, ask for it
    NSLog(@"No permission");

    [FBSession.activeSession
     requestNewPublishPermissions:
     [NSArray arrayWithObject:@"publish_actions"]
     defaultAudience:FBSessionDefaultAudienceFriends
     completionHandler:^(FBSession *session, NSError *error) {
         if (!error) {
             // If permissions granted, publish the story
             [self postStatusWithGraphAPI];
         }
     }];
} else {
    // If permissions present, publish the story
    [self postStatusWithGraphAPI];
}
```

}

the method postStatusWithGraphAPI:

```
- (void) postStatusWithGraphAPI{

[FBRequestConnection startForPostStatusUpdate:@"User-generated status update."
                            completionHandler:^(FBRequestConnection *connection, id result, NSError *error) {
                                if (!error) {
                                    // Status update posted successfully to Facebook
                                    NSLog(@"result: %@", result);
                                } else {
                                    // An error occurred, we need to handle the error
                                    // See: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/errors
                                    NSLog(@"%@", error.description);
                                }
                            }];
```

}

This view controller does not handle the facebook login of the app, which is handled in another view controller, namely MyViewController. Breifly talking, the flow is like:

1. Perform Facebook login in View_A (MyViewController)
2. Press a specific button in View_A, invoke push segue to View_B (which is the view containing the code segment above)
3. User press the update status button in View_B

After I press the update status button, as I don't have the publish permission, the app should ask me to grant additional permission to the app. However, instead for asking for additional permission, the message "You have already authorized this application" occurred with the options "OK" and "Cancel".

And after I pressed "OK", I still don't have publish permission, hence unable to post the status, the the following error message occurred:

> 2014-06-12 19:11:18.545 TestingApp[4130:60b] FBSDKLog: An existing state change handler was assigned to the session and will be overwritten.
>
> 2014-06-12 19:11:18.548 TestingApp[4130:60b] Session opened
>
> 2014-06-12 19:11:20.822 TestingApp[4130:60b] No permission
>   2014-06-12 19:11:23.186 TestingApp[4130:60b] FBSDKLog: An existing state change handler was assigned to the session and will be overwritten.
>
> 2014-06-12 19:11:23.640 TestingApp[4130:60b] Error Domain=com.facebook.sdk Code=5 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (com.facebook.sdk error 5.)" UserInfo=0x8c56320
>
> {com.facebook.sdk:HTTPStatusCode=403, com.facebook.sdk:ParsedJSONResponseKey={
>      body =     {
>          error =         {
>              code = 200;
>              message = "(#200) The user hasn't authorized the application to perform this > action";
>              type = OAuthException;
>          };
>      };
>      code = 403;
>
> }, com.facebook.sdk:ErrorSessionKey=, 
>   expirationDate: 2014-08-11 11:11:19 +0000, refreshDate: 2014-06-12 11:11:23 +0000, 
>   attemptedRefreshDate: 0001-12-30 00:00:00 +0000, permissions:(
>      installed,
>      "public_profile",
>      email,
>      "user_friends"
>   )>}

Comment: I've had similar problems with another API (Twitter I think), so the issue might not be exactly the same, but I remember I solved mine by re-issuing an app secret with the expected OAuth scopes. Also make sure that you have specified all scopes your app requires in your Facebook Developper app page.

Comment: @Romain: Sorry I am new to this, do you mean resetting the App Secret in my app page in Facebook developer page? As for the permission scope, there are only 3 listed in the page Status & review, which are email, public_profile and user_friends. And it seems that there is no way to add additional permission there?

Comment: Forget my previous comment, it might not be applicable to Facebook SDK. Is your app still in developer/sandbox mode? I read on Facebook Developers website (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions/v2.0) that requesting for `publish_actions` permission requires reviewing from the Facebook team. If your app is considered "in production" and not in sandbox mode, it might be normal that your request for new permissions is being rejected.

Comment: Also, independently from the problem you're currently facing, in your `if (!error)` block code, you should not assume that you successfully got the permissions from the user: he might have rejected the request, so you need to check once again for `publish_actions` by doing something like `if ([FBSession.activeSession.permissions indexOfObject:@"publish_actions"] == NSNotFound) { // permissions not granted } else { // your code }`.

Comment: Did you ever manage to find a solution to this issue?